# How can we change the create order button link on ORO Commerce?

Tags: php, symfony, orocrm, orocommerce

We need to change create order button link like: baseurl/sso/checkout/

Like on this screenshot 
[image: screenshot]

I have created the bundle extension and when we this bundle extension add-in our app then all create order link change to our custom URL.

How can we possibly need to change programmatically?

And How can we every cart order data get to our custom URL page?

Answer (score 0):

> How can we possibly need to change programmatically?

You can remove the original button that comes from workflow and insert the new one with [the layout update](https://doc.oroinc.com/frontend/storefront/layouts/#dev-doc-frontend-layouts-layout-updates), but it's highly not recommended.

Checkout in OroCommerce uses a workflow engine, that is highly customizable. We recommend customizing the workflow instead.

> How can we every cart order data get to our custom URL page?

To customize the checkout process, it is preferred to use [the custom workflow](https://doc.oroinc.com/master/backend/entities-data-management/workflows/) based on one of the [built-in checkout workflows](https://doc.oroinc.com/master/user/back-office/system/workflows/system-workflows/checkout/#system-workflows-checkout-workflow).

As an example of customization, there is [an alternative checkout workflow](https://doc.oroinc.com/master/user/back-office/system/workflows/system-workflows/alternative-checkout/) available out of the box.

Comment: I have tried but we facing issues so, how to change create order link or set custom workflow?